# Story about A father and a son who are from another planet and are adapted to human lives

Tags: story-identification, aliens, novel

**Plot Details**

I unfortunately don't remember any character names, or details, I believe the boy's mother is deceased. The memories of this book are lost because there's a huge gap in time since I've seen, let alone read it. I believe they spoke English and another language which probably wasn't earthly. The son and father were trying to cope with the loss of the mother, they may also plan to continue to stay on Earth, live human lives.

**Chronology and other information**

The book I'm looking for is blue, it reads 300+ pages, it is not a children's book. It is a science fiction novel.

I want to say the book is from the year 2000, but it may be a few years older. This is all I could remember.

Comment: Any more information? Examples: general publication date, any specific plot events, was it a children's book, what did the son and father do? As it stands this question is far to broad.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152708/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!